# SingleValueEncodingContainerとKeyedEncodingContainerでEncodableを型に持つ変数をエンコードする時の挙動の違いについて(KeyedEncodingContainerだとエラーが出る)

Tags: swift, ios, swift4

swift初心者です。

```
let foo: Encodable
```

などの`Encodable`の型を持つ変数を`JSONEncoder`でエンコードしたいです。
調べたところ、https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-encode-objects-of-unknown-type/12253
のサイトより、

```
import Foundation

extension Encodable {
    fileprivate func encode(to container: inout SingleValueEncodingContainer) throws {
        try container.encode(self)
    }
}

struct AnyEncodable1 : Encodable {
    var value: Encodable
    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try value.encode(to: &container)
    }
}

struct MyThing : Encodable {
    let myURL = AnyEncodable1(URL(string: "http://swift.org")!)
}

let url = URL(string: "http://swift.org")
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
var data = try encoder.encode(MyThing())
```

とすると`Encodable`の変数もエンコードできることがわかりました。

しかし、このコードだと`Encodable`を`AnyEncodable`1つにつき1個しか保存できません。

そこで、

```
extension Encodable {
    fileprivate func encode<K>(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<K>, for key: CodingKey {
        try container.encode(self, forKey: key) 
        // error: Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Self, forKey: CodingKey)'
    }
}

struct AnyEncodable1 : Encodable {
    var value: Encodable
    init(_ value: Encodable) {
        self.value = value
    }
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try value.encode(to: &container, for: .value)
    }
}

struct MyThing : Encodable {
    let myURL = AnyEncodable1(URL(string: "http://swift.org")!)
}

let url = URL(string:  "http://swift.org")
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
var data = try encoder.encode(MyThing())
```

というように`SingleValueEncodingContainer`を`KeyedEncodingContainer`に入れ替えました。しかし、入れ替えると先程までは出ていなかったエラーが出ました。
`SingleValueEncodingContainer`と`KeyedEncodingContainer`のencodeメソッドの宣言はそれぞれ

```
// SingleValueEncodingContainer
mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T) throws where T : Encodable
// KeyedEncodingContainer
mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer.Key) throws where T : Encodable
```

と`KeyedEncodingContainer`にはキーが必要だということ以外は変わりません。
しかし、なぜ`KeyedEncodingContainer`ではエラーが出るのでしょうか。
ちなみに`UnkeyedEncodingContainer`に入れ替えるとエラーは出ませんでした。
なぜこのようになるか理由を教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。
swift4、xcode9.2です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メソッドヘッダの宣言が少し間違えています。(`) throws`が抜けてまずがそれは置いといて。)

---

まずは、`KeyedEncodingContainer.encode(_:forKey:)`の宣言をよくご覧ください。

```
// KeyedEncodingContainer
mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer.Key) throws where T : Encodable
```

`forKey`パラメータの型は任意の`CodingKey`型ではなく、`KeyedEncodingContainer.Key`型、つまりそのコンテナの`Key`型でないといけません。

その定義はこうなっています。

[KeyedEncodingContainer.Key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyedencodingcontainer/key)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> typealias KeyedEncodingContainer<K>.Key = K
> ```

となっており、要は`KeyedEncodingContainer`のジェネリック型パラメータ`K`と同じ型を表しています。

---

あなたのメソッド宣言を見るとこうなっています。

```
fileprivate func encode<K>(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<K>, for key: CodingKey)
```

この宣言ですと、パラメータ`key`は、`container`の型に関係なく、`CodingKey`に適合する型ならなんでも良いことになります。これでは先の`KeyedEncodingContainer.encode(_:forKey:)`メソッドを呼ぶことはできません。

以下のように`key`の型を書き換えてみてください。

```
extension Encodable {
    fileprivate func encode<K>(to container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<K>, for key: K) throws {
        try container.encode(self, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

これで、`key`は`encode(_:forKey:)`の宣言にある制約を満たすことになるので、その部分でのエラーは出なくなるはずです。

Comment: 丁寧なご指摘をありがとうございます。keyの型をKに書き換えたところ、KeyedEncodingContainerでもエンコードすることができました。